# Cursor won't hide in full screen youtube video

Tags: 15.04, video, youtube, html5

I'm using ubuntu 15.04 and when i enter full screen on youtube video my cursor won't hide, it's annoying af. Any solution?

Comment: My right telepathy antenna has broken off and you're too far away from me to link directly to your computer.  **;-)**  Therefore, please [edit] your question and add more information like video hardware/software
, browser (and version) ....